# My app is working fine in the emulator, but not in the real device

Tags: android

I am using Android studio 2.3 and Nexus 6 API 25 as emulator.I have created a app where I use to log in through firebase and display some images URL.Everything works fine when I run the app in emulator.
But when run the app in a real android device, the app installs and I could signup with a new user & password and checked json databse in firebase for new entry.

Till the above app works fine in real device.but when I went for login , app stops with message"Unfortunately, the app has stopped".

I followed below steps in order to  troubleshoot but error still remains

1.Disabled Instant run.
2.added  android:largeHeap="true" in manifest.xml to prevent from out of memory issue
3.Build .apk file in android studio and transfer to real device.

I am attaching here my gradle files, manifest files.

******build.gradle**:-****

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.win81.eathut"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //Add Library

    compile 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

****AndroidManifest.xml****

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.win81.eathut">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SignIn" />
        <activity android:name=".SignUp" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".List" />
        <activity android:name=".Detail"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My real device spec is 
Model-Samsung SM-G530H
Android version:-5.0.2,API 21

Please help me.

Note:I can easily run any react native apps in this device.

Comment: please add your stacktrace

Comment: enable multidex options